# Authorization header malformed on post request with Basic auth (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch

I am trying to create a new user on a wordpress site remotely, I am using the rest api available natively on all wp websites, the issue I am having is that in order to create new user you have to authenticate using an administrator account, when sending the request I got the error:

```
Object {
  "code": "jwt_auth_bad_auth_header",
  "data": Object {
    "status": 403,
  },
  "message": "Authorization header malformed.",
}
```

My function is all fine except those headers if anybody can help

```
signup = (e) => {
    let { username, email, password, password2 } = this.state
    if (username !== '' && email !== '' && password !== '') {
      if (password === password2) {
        this.setState({ loading: true, error: null })
        var auth = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('coolusername' + ':' + 'securepassword')
        console.log(auth)
        var url = 'https://example.com'
        var request = new Request(url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/users', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': auth
          }),
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password
          })
        })
        fetch(request)
          .then((response) => {
            response.json().then((results) => {
             // ...
            })
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
          })
      } else {
        this.setState({ error: 'Passwords do not match' })
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({ error: 'Error: Missing fields' })
    }
  }
```

The thing I believe is causing this error is that `'Authorization'` should be followed with base64 username:password but when I try to decode the string I have passed I obtain a different string not exactly what I have inputed, I have previously used `js-base64` npm library it works just fine.

Comment: From what I can tell, WordPress doesn't support the Authentication header at all by default

Answer (score 0):

if anybody is looking for solution later on, I have fixed the issue by using a different plugin, .htaccess file and wp-config.php files requires no additional modification.

Also `authorization header` is not required at all.

**wp-rest-user**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/

> To Register a User using REST API, send a POST request to
>   /wp-json/wp/v2/users/register, with a JSON body (Set header:
>   content-type: application/json) with three keys: username, email and
>   password.
>
> To Retrieve Password using REST API, send a POST request to
>   /wp-json/wp/v2/users/lost-password, including a JSON (Set header:
>   content-type: application/json) body with three keys: user_login.